# how to define a command object inside a controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I have started to look into command object as a means for validating a form that has no domain associated with it.
On my research, i found out that a command object either can be declared in the same package as my controller or in the controller class itself.

However, all the examples that I have seen so far have a separate command object class bot not inside the controller.

Can anyone show me an example or code to define a command object inside my controller itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about command object classes.  You can declare them as an inner class inside your controller like this:

```
class MyController {

    class ActionCommand {
        String paramName
    }

    def action(ActionCommand actionCommand) {
        render actionCommand.paramName
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically they're top-level classes but are in the same .groovy file as the controller that uses them.